# axios post request body is wrong

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, axios

I'm trying to connect my react app to my node api.
I managed to get data, but when I try to post data, the body format is all wrong.
I followd the [axios docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example).

this is my code:

```
import Axios from "axios";

const api = Axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8000",
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
});


await api.post("/",{data:"someData"});
    populateData(); // a function that gets data from server
```

when I log the `req.body` in the server, this is what I get

```
{ '{"data":"someData"}': '' }
```

When I didn't set any header, the body was empty.
So with a little research I tried to put other types of headers but didn't find solutions

Comment: Why are you trying to force the content-type to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?  It appears you want JSON here.

Comment: when I force ```application/json ``` the ```req.body``` is empty

Comment: And, as you apparently discovered, you weren't parsing JSON on the server which is why `req.body` was empty.  Anyway, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

the solution was at the express config.
I didn't add a middleware to parse json requests, only urlencoded ones.

once I added this code to express, and set config type to `application-json` it worked

```
app.use(express.json());
```